# Is there any leeway with choosing my starting items if I'm starting at a level higher than 1?

Tags: magic-items, character-creation, pathfinder-2e

I'm preparing a Cleric for a *Pathfinder 2nd Ed* campaign and reached a bit of an impasse. Going by [Table 10-10](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=572), my character should have one permanent 2nd level item, 2 permanent 1st level items and 25GP of other funds. The problem is that the 1st level items are either redundant (everburning torch and dull aeon stone) or are unusable for my character (Heavy Armors). Considering these factors, I have a few questions:

**1) Can a selection of a permanent item be exchanged for multiple selections of consumable items of the same level? If so, how many?**

**2) Can you take a lump sum of GP instead of a permanent item? If so, how much?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The relevant rules are here: https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=587

It looks like you're looking for this text:

> If you choose, you can allow the player to instead start with a lump sum of currency and buy whatever common items they want, with a maximum item level of 1 lower than the character’s level. This has a lower total value than the normal allotment of permanent items and currency, since the player can select a higher ratio of high-level items.

So, Rules As Written, your choice would be to either take 25gp and a second-level item and two first-level items, or a lump sum of 75gp with which to buy items.

(Comparing levels 1 and 2 on that table, it looks like the rules believe that a first-level item is worth 10gp.)

Your other option would be to take the most valuable first-level item (the 18gp Half Plate) and sell it for half price.

There don't appear to be any rules for exchanging permanent item draws for anything else.  This is the sort of thing that you could ask your DM about, but my prediction is that your DM will tell you that they'd prefer that you take the 10gp or 9gp, rather than issuing homebrew for it.

Comment: Those rules don't allow players to choose whether to take the GP or wealth by level, they allow the GM to choose. Otherwise +1.

Comment: Technically true!  It's technically also true that the rules don't allow players to choose which items they get, because the GM chooses that too.  It sounds like in this case the GM has delegated these choices to the players.

Comment: @DanB Kind of. It makes it clear that it's the GM's job to approve of the list, but says that "if they know what items they want their character to have, respect their choices unless you believe those choices will have a negative impact on your game". That is, essentially, it's the GM's *responsibility* to hand out the items, but it's mostly up to the player if they want to prioritize them. So while what you say is accurate, it is misleading out of context.

Comment: The lump sum is *entirely* a GM choice, but it wouldn't be inappropriate for a player to request it (especially in this situation)